# Javascript / node.js - callbacks inside Promise

Tags: node.js, events, npm, callback, promise

i have some callbacks inside my promise:

```
var res = new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log('trig1');
  var out = fs.createWriteStream(pathToFile);
  console.log('trig2');
  out.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('out finish')
  })
  out.on('close', function() {
    console.log('out close')
  })
  out.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('out error: ' + err)
  })
})
```

When i call this promise, it creates the file on the path and prints:

```
trig1
trig2
```

Nothing more. Why are my callbacks not executed?

Greetings and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there was no error, you didn't write anything, and you didn't close this stream. That's why any of those events fired.

Try to change your code so it will do something.

```
var res = new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log('trig1');
  var out = fs.createWriteStream(pathToFile);
  console.log('trig2');
  out.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('out finish')
  })
  out.on('close', function() {
    console.log('out close')
  })
  out.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('out error: ' + err)
  });
  out.close(); // this will fire `close` event
})
```